# Do I pay twice for enchanted items when using Ritual Path magic?

Tags: magic-items, gurps-4e, gurps

In GURPS *Thaumatology: Ritual Path Magic* players have the option of a form of enhanced loot. You design a magic item, GM brings it into play. You start out paying the full cost to get it into play, but do you have to pay that cost again to attune to the item after it has been looted?

I'm concerned this might be the case from reading these:

- Under “Acquiring Enchanted Items” on page 34 of *Thaumatology: Ritual Path Magic* it says

  > #### Coincidence
  >
  > If the player has something specific in mind, he may use a more proactive version of Looting (above). He and the GM sit down and come up with the item […]
  >   The GM will then work with the player to introduce the item into the game in a believable way
- Whereas looting says

  > ... losing about 10% effectiveness per day (the details are up to the GM). In all cases, if the looter wants to keep the item, he has to pay its character-point cost to “attune” to it.

Answer (score 5):

No, you don't have to pay for it again. You've paid for it up-front. GURPS never asks for you to pay for things twice in character points: they're a metagame idea that's not supposed to be (too) visible within the game.

GURPS also subscribes strongly to Rule Zero (There is a GM, and s/he is sensible) and doesn't try very hard to write rules to resist perverse or malicious interpretation.